# WFFM - Send Email With Attachment not working in 8.1 160523

Tags: wffm, custom-field

I am working with WFFM Upload File and was asked to send the file by attaching it in the Email. So I created a custom Save Action that is almost the same with the OOTB Send Email Message except for an additional xml configuration :

```
 <IncludeAttachments>true</IncludeAttachments>
```

[image: IncludeAttachments]

In my end, it only puts link in the Email and saves the file to the Media Library instead of attaching the files in the Email.

[image: Email attached]

[image: Media Library]

The above configuration and behavior is based on the link below:

https://sitecorejunkie.com/2014/10/17/turn-off-the-attaching-of-files-in-emails-sent-by-web-forms-for-marketers-in-sitecore/amp/

I am not sure if this works in WFFM 8.1 160523 as some references are now `Sitecore.WFFM.Actions.SaveActions.SendMessage` instead of `Sitecore.Form.Submit.SendMessage`.

Please advice me on this.

Comment: If you still have an issue with this then please check out my answer here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5482/reading-a-value-from-an-wffm-upload-file-field

Comment: @AdamSeabridge I have tried this but still not working. Same behavior as stated above.

Comment: Ok give creating a custom save action a go and log out what is happening like so: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7206/how-to-get-formid-form-name-and-the-site-name-while-uploading-a-file-from-cd-ser/7216#7216

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is now included out of the box with WFFM, no need for custom save action:

1. Navigate to **/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions/Send Email Message** item.
2. In Parameters field add the following:

```
<IsIncludeAttachments>true</IsIncludeAttachments>
```

3. Save and publish changes.

I have it working on Sitecore 8.1 instance.