# WFFM Custom Save Action Attachment Different Between CM and CD

Tags: wffm

I had this piece of code to capture every form submission and send the form input as an email. However, we found that the code behave differently between CM and CD environment.

```
   public class FeedbackSendEmailAction : WffmSaveAction
   {
       public virtual void Submit(ID formid, AdaptedResultList fields)
       {
           try
           {
               string attachPath = string.Empty;
               foreach (AdaptedControlResult formField in fields)
               {
                   if (formField.FieldName.Equals("Attachment"))
                   {
                       attachPath = formField.Value;
                   }

               }
               ...
               //send email etc
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
             //do some logging
           }
       }
   }
```

On **CM** environment, the `formField.Value` returns path where the item is stored (e.g. ). While on **CD** environment it will returns `Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Actions.PostedFile` as if it was a string and we can't cast it. Decompiling the assembly gave us the following:

```
//Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Actions
[Serializable]
public class AdaptedControlResult : ControlResult
{
    public new string Value
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}

//Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Actions
[KnownType(typeof(PostedFile))]
[Serializable]
[SoapInclude(typeof(PostedFile))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(PostedFile))]
public class ControlResult
{
    public object Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I am aware that the `AdaptedControlResult` extends `ControlResult` that exposes `Value` as `object` and we might be able to fetch the `PostedFile` in `ControlResult`'s  `Value` field with ease if we cast the `AdaptedControlResult` into `ControlResult`.Unfortunately, it did not work as expected and returns null..

My question are:

- Why does it behave differently?
- How to fetch the attached file `byte[]` or `Stream` in **CD** environment if its possible?

Comment: Do you have “Client Action” checked for this save action? If checked, the code executes on the CD server. If not checked, then the form save action gets processed via the event queue. Client Action is a very common box to check whenever dealing with custom save actions. My hunch is that by not checking it, the serialization process of storing the form submission improperly casts the value as that unexpected type name.

Comment: its checked. anything else i should check?

Comment: Bagus have a look at my answer here, it might help you: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5482/reading-a-value-from-an-wffm-upload-file-field

Answer (score 0):

See my comment above about a similar issue I was having. Changing the setting below should mean your posted file is available on CD Servers too and will have a value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:x="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <settings>
            <setting name="WFM.IsRemoteActions" value="false" />
        </settings>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: hmm, its not exactly empty though `AdaptedControlResult.Value` returns `Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Actions.PostedFile`. and i am sure that we have the `WFM.IsRemoteActions` not set on CD. I will let you know once i've checked on this. thank you for the answer.

Comment: No problem. Take a look at some of the code Jonathan has in his post to read the file value and see how you get on: https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2015/02/18/sitecore-web-forms-for-marketers-send-email-with-attachment-save-action/